# View in flex: 1 not expanding to full height, KeyboardAvoidingView not working properly

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I'm having an issue about a ScrollView that does not take the full height that remains, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5lYr.png).

The view with red borders is supposed to go all the way down, and as a result the view doesn't go up enough when the keyboard is out [and the 5th item is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i7dA.png).

There's my code for this component :

```
    <Container>
      <Header navigation={this.props.navigation} title="Header" />
        <ScrollView style={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          borderColor: '#F00',
          borderWidth: 1,
        }}>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView behaviour="padding" keyboardVerticalOffset={50} style={{
            flex: 1,
          }}>
            <InputWithLabel label="1st item" editable={true} onTextChange={this.textChange} />
            <InputWithLabel label="2nd item" editable={true} onTextChange={this.textChange} />
            <InputWithLabel label="3rd item" editable={true} onTextChange={this.textChange} />
            <InputWithLabel label="4th item" editable={true} onTextChange={this.textChange} />
            <InputWithLabel label="5th item" editable={true} onTextChange={this.textChange} />
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>

        </ScrollView>
    </Container>
```

And this is my root component, I also use react-navigation to display my components :

```
      <Root>
        <StatusBar translucent={false} barStyle="light-content" />
        <Provider store={store}>
          <AppRoot/>
        </Provider>
      </Root>
```

I tried messing with the keyboardVerticalOffset parameter but it doesn't seem to do anything in my situation. I also tried to put "flex: 1" instead of "flexGrow: 1" on the scrollview, but [this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkbs4.png).

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {
  Dimensions,  // <--- this
  ...
} from 'react-native'

const { height } = Dimensions.get('window')  // <--- this

<Container>
  <Header navigation={this.props.navigation} title="Header" />
    <ScrollView style={{
      flexGrow: 1,
      borderColor: '#F00',
      borderWidth: 1,
    }}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behaviour="padding" keyboardVerticalOffset={50} style={{
        flex: 1,
      }}>
         <View style={{ minHeight: height }}>      // <--- this
           <InputWithLabel label="1st item" editable={true} onTextChange={this.textChange} />
           <InputWithLabel label="2nd item" editable={true} onTextChange={this.textChange} />
           <InputWithLabel label="3rd item" editable={true} onTextChange={this.textChange} />
           <InputWithLabel label="4th item" editable={true} onTextChange={this.textChange} />
           <InputWithLabel label="5th item" editable={true} onTextChange={this.textChange} />
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>

    </ScrollView>
</Container>
```

Comment: Is there no other way to achieve this ? It feels kind of wrong to put a fixed height to the content when flex: 1 is supposed to expand the content  the way I want it to.

Comment: You can try adding `contentContainerStyle={{
      flexGrow: 1}}` to `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

well what I did was to increase flex of the form with KeyboardAvoidingView and I used behavior="position" because with the others doesn't work.

for example:

```
import React from "react";
import Wrapper from "../../components/auth/authBackWrapper";
import SignInTitle from "../../components/auth/signIn/signInTitle";
import SignInForm from "../../components/auth/signIn/signInForm";
import SignInLinks from "../../components/auth/signIn/signInLinks";
import SignInButton from "../../components/auth/signIn/SignInButton";
import { Content } from "../../components/commonStyledComponents/commonStyledComponents";

import styled from "styled-components/native";

const KeyboarAvoid = styled.KeyboardAvoidingView`
    flex: 2.4;
`;

export default ({ }) =>
    <Wrapper>
        <Content p={20}>
            <SignInTitle />
            <KeyboarAvoid behavior='position'>
                <SignInForm />
            </KeyboarAvoid>
            <SignInButton />
            <SignInLinks />
        </Content>
    </Wrapper>
```